# Excel SelectionChanged event is not firing

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, office-js

Dev Chain: Microsoft Visual Studio Code, Excel Online Addin, Debug with Chrome

I have been developing an Excel Add-in, with no problems using the above tools for quite some time.  Recently, I have been having issues where the Excel `SelectionChanged` event is not firing when running the debug version, despite a successful call (and async callback) to `AddHandlerAsync`.  Only one in ten calls or so will actually successfully set up the hook.

I have not changed anything major in my code, but my organization did recently implement MDM on all devices, including desktops and laptops. This is a huge impediment to my productivity, as you might imagine.

I am using React (`create-react-app`) and `office-ui-fabric-react`.

I have the following code to set up the callback:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Office.initialize = (reason) => {
        console.log('Office.initialize called with reason = ' + reason)

        Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(
            Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged,
            (eventArgs) => {
                this.onExcelSelectionChanged(eventArgs)
            },
            (asyncResult) => {
                if (asyncResult.status == "succeeded") {
                    console.log('Selection changed handler was added')
                } else {
                    console.log(`Error setting event: ${JSON.stringify(asyncResult)}`);
                }
            })
    }
})
```

The call succeeds, but when running in VS Code debugger (with Debugger for Chrome extension), the event does not fire.  This previously worked fine.  It seems to work fine in the production environment.

Edit 2/23/2018:

I seem to have solved my problem for the most part. I am using React Router, and had `Office.initialize` functions set up for each path.

In trying to sort out the problem, I created a whole new Add-in with `create-react-app` as described in [Build an Excel add-in using React](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-get-started-react).  I noticed that the `Office.initialize` is in `index.js`, wrapping the `ReactDOM.render(...)` call.  I rejiggered things in my code to emulate this, and now it seems to work a lot better, though it still misses the hook every once in a while.

Comment: Can you add sample code for a minimal repro?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Thansk for the quick response.  I updated with some code, but will see what I can do to set up a better repro.

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried using the new API `let handler = workbook.onSelectionChanged.add(onSelectionChanged);` This of course needs to be inside a batch. There is an example shown in the Script Lab Excel samples that you can look-up for reference.

Comment: Thanks @SudhiRamamurthy - I was not aware of that API, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to `Office.t initialize`, the number one rule is to assign your function *as early as possible*. Office can't wire up your add-in until you assign `Office.initialize` and it can be pretty aggressive about timing-out if it takes too long (it differs a little between platforms by 5 seconds is the [guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn)).

Without seeing how you've stood up `react-router` it is difficult to know for sure what is happening. That said, your `index.js` should look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Office = window.Office;

Office.initialize = (reason) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
  registerServiceWorker();
};
```

Note that this isn't wrapped in `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {}`. This is important because waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` means you're waiting *too long* before assigning `Office.initialize`. Instead, we're wiring Office up before we wire up `react` or `react-router-dom`.

If you wanted to wait for the DOM to load, you would do this inside your initialize function:

```
Office.initialize = reason => {
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
    registerServiceWorker();
  });
};
```

With that said, I've never run into a need for this myself. I would suggest forgoing `DOMContentLoaded` initially. You can always add it if you find a specific need for it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience. Did you encounter the problem on both online and desktop version?

There is a [another issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/69) which is under investigation. Is there any debugging info you can share with us?

Comment: I have only tried it on the browser so far - I will investigate further.